# Twice a week syllabus

Tags: datetime

I was trying to adapt the following code from three-times a week to two-times a week, unsuccessfully. Also, I want to change the date format so that it shows: Mon Jan 28. Any help appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{advdate,datetime}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{advdate,datetime}
\newenvironment{schedule}
  {\par\longdate\renewcommand{\item}{\par%
    \stepcounter{mycntr}\ifnum\value{mycntr}>3\relax%
      \setcounter{mycntr}{0}\AdvanceDate[3]%
    \else
      \AdvanceDate[2]%
    \fi\today\quad}
  }{\par}
\newcounter{mycntr}
\begin{document}
\begin{schedule}
  \item Something
  \item Something else
  \item Relax
  \item Go to the sea
  \item Something
  \item Something else
  \item Relax
  \item Go to the sea
\end{schedule}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Twice a week... which days?

Comment: Mon and Wed; and Tu and Thu